# Finding if the document is unique

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am querying 3 collections in MongoDB and then creating a new document by taking some fields from the documents of the 3 separate collections. For example: I am taking field 'A' from first collection, field 'B' from second and field 'C' from third.

Using them i am creating a json document like

```
var uploadDoc = {
                   'A' : <value of A>,
                   'B' : <value of B>,
                   'C' : <value of C>,
                }
```

This uploadDoc is being uploaded to another collection.

Question: I wish to upload only distinct values of uploadDoc. By default MongoDB gives each uploadDoc a unique id. How do I insert `uplodDoc`s to the collection only when another document with the same A, B and C values hasn't been inserted before?

I am using javascript to query the collections and create docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways are simple:

1. use "upserts"

   ```js
   db.collection.update(uploadDoc,uploadDoc,{ "upsert": true })
   ```
2. Use a unique index

   ```js
   db.collection.ensureIndex({ "A": 1, "B": 1, "C": 1 },{ "unique": true });
   db.collection.insert(uploadDoc); // Same thing fails :(
   ```

Both work. Choose one.

Comment: @displayName The first way looks for a document that matches the criteria and tries to update it. If nothing is actually changed then MongoDB does not really do anything. If that document is not found then a new one is created. All explained in the manual pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Unique Indexes: [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-indexes)

You shouldn't use upsert without unique indexes:

> To avoid inserting the same document more than once, only use **upsert: true** if the query field is uniquely indexed.

because

> Consider when multiple clients issue the following update with an upsert parameter at the same time:

[cut]

> If all update() operations complete the query portion before any client successfully inserts data, and there is no unique index on the name field, then each update operation may result in an insert.

[from here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#use-unique-indexes)